# How to set http status code when responding to servlet client from Filter class-method in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, filter

I am writing a webservice with spring (this question is not about spring...) that implements a (hopefully) restful api. From my understanding all response should be in xml or json format. This is not really a big deal in most cases. But in one situation this seems not possible. I am using a facility from tomcat where a servlet is involved. I have to use a filter for some reason (and this reason is authentication). As I am new to servlets my understanding is eventually not so well, but to me it looks like this

My filter-class derives from javax.servlet.filter and I am writing my code within the doFilter method:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { // ... }
```

And at some point i realize i have to respond to the client with http status code 401 and also want to give him a xml or json information about what happened. Now to me it looks as if i can either

1) Use the ServletResponse: This allows me to get an OutputStream and write my xml/json out. However I cannot set the http status code at all. The final response arriving at the client does contain some http headers.

2) Cast ServletResponse to HttpServletResponse: This allows me to set status code, but I don't seem to be able to set the response body, but let response body be handled from tomcat.

Either way seems incomplete. If i use ServletResponse to write to the OutputStream and then cast to HttpServletResponse and then call sendError(401) - hoping that whatever I wrote to OutputStream reaches the client - my response does not contain an http "status line". However http headers are present like "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1"

any help welcome...

Comment: Implementing REST in servlets is quite low level in my opinion. If possible I would try to use JAX-RS with Jersey for example, which is more convenient.

Comment: I did not describe my situation to well... Please look at updated question. rest api is done with spring.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've implemented a filter for authentication shortly. I've coded something similar to this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain)
{
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) resp;

    boolean authenticated=false;
    // perform authentication

    if (authenticated)
    {
         chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }
    else
    {
         // don't continue the chain
         response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
         response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "BASIC realm=\"Your realm\"");

         response.setContentType("what you need");
         PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();

         // don't set content length , don't close
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send user defined status code e.g 498 , with custom message?

Comment: @Sanjeev - I didn't try it, but I guess it's possible, because the code is simply an integer. Maybe, other components in your infrastructure only accept status covered by the standards

Comment: If I'm using PrintWriter, getting below exception in logs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response. When I'm switching to outputStream(), then I'm not able to set http status code in the response.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
    ServletException {

    response.resetBuffer();
    response.getOutputStream().write("Your content".getBytes());
    HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    hsr.setStatus(401);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: why do you continue with the filter chain after setting status 401 ? The filters before the authentication are executed anyway

Comment: @Ulrich It may not be required to continue with the filter chain but it depends on the specific setup of filters in the web.xml.

Comment: You're right, of course `web.xml` affects the order of filter execution. But in generally, it doesn't make sense do continue processing a request that isn't authenticated. If there are tasks to be execute (such as logging), they should executed in filters that are chained ahead of authentication.

Comment: What if subsequent filters want to set headers? I am coming here in a search why my filter which sets CORS headers does not fire.

Answer (score 2):

Method HttpServletResponse::sendError is working for me to return from filter in SpringBoot 2.0 application:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
if (authenticated)
    {
         chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }
    else
    {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), "Authorization shall be provided");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: This allows me to set status code, but I don't seem to be able to set the custom response body, using getOutputStream(). Not able to add code snippet here as it leads to unformatted code.

Comment: @PiyushUpadhyay - post a new question. There you can add a MCVE or something similar. It's possible to put a custom body in the response, but not after closing the OutputStream