# Set status code for response to 404 using Filter, if status code is 403

Tags: java, httpresponse, servlet-filters

I want to set a status code of 404 on outgoing response using Servlet Filter, if the status code was initially going to be 403. This is basically because I want to prevent any attacker from knowing about the existence of the resource.

I know this cannot be accomplished by simple HttpServletResponse - changing the response code inside `if(status==403)` condition after `chain.dofilter()` does nothing, because the response has already been commited.

I tried the code given in the answer here - [Response is committing and doFilter chain is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025605/response-is-committing-and-dofilter-chain-is-broken/11027170#11027170)

But it gives me the following error:-

```
java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:125)
at CODE.filter.ResourceNotFoundFilter.doFilter(ResourceNotFoundFilter.java:76)
```

I think that the above answer includes more than I require, and I want to strip away the unrequired parts, but I'm not sure which those are. Also, I have multiple filters and this one has to be the last in the chain. Do I have to create a response wrapper from the start and pass that wrapper through all filters? Or can I use simple HttpServletResponse for all the filters before this one?

The error generated above is basically because of this line in the code. This is the 76th line in my file.

`response.getOutputStream().write(wrapper.getWrapperBytes());`

Expected result - I want to change the status code to 404 if it was initially going to be 403, using Filters.

Actual result - I can't get it to work.

Please help.

Comment: Note that this is *typically* a user-hostile approach, as it makes it much more difficult to debug client code.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767502/how-to-set-http-status-code-when-responding-to-servlet-client-from-filter-class

Comment: @chrylis, why is that? Actually we used the IBM AppScan tool to detect vulnerabilities and one of them was that folders such as style or script if accessed directly were coming up as forbidden. The security report suggested that we either remove those folders completely or issue a 404 code for them.

Comment: @ushort, I saw that thread, but couldn't relate it to my problem. I need to do something in the Filter after the request has been processed, while that thread talks about authentication done before the request is processed, and uses if-else condition based on result of authentication.

Comment: The problem is that if I'm an authorized user trying to make something work with your server, I can't tell the difference between "correct address but my credentials are wrong" and "wrong address". It's the entire point of having different codes in the first place. There *can* be reasonable justification for doing it this way, but it imposes a significant cost on your consumers.

Comment: I'm using WildFly, so wrong credentials are handled in a completely different way (j_security_check).

Comment: Never mind, I made it work using an answer from WildFly community.